# Roadmap to create a scientific computing website

Tags: python, django, web-servers

I am a theoretical physicist starting my Ph.D. shortly. As a side project, I would like to create a scientific computing website in the field of General Relativity. It should be an interactive database that allows one to explore various exact solutions of the Einstein equations.

I have some background in web developing, and I know a fair amount of PHP -- but I sense that this project is too big to code everything from scratch. Right now I am in the process of planning the roadmap. So far I have:

- a small Linux webserver ($20 a month or so) will be the basis
- Gunicorn as a WSGI
- use Django as web framework
- use NumPy and SciPy for computations; Matplotlib for vislualization; MathJax for displaying formulae

I don't expect this website to have more than a dozen visits each day, so performance is not an issue. So here is my question: is there any obvious point in the above roadmap that I am missing?

Comment: timday's answer further below is an example how my question can be answered, so I do not think it should be put on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few thoughts:

- $20/month seems excessive for a site with a handful of visits a day.  If you've not used Amazon's EC2 before, take a look at the "micro" instances.  You can get a year's "[free tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/)" use for virtually nothing, and then if things are working out, paying for three years upfront (for a "reserved instance") works out more like around $6-$7/month from what I remember.
- Depending what you're trying to achieve, would simply cooking up your material as an ipython notebook and hosting it online via [nbviewer](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/) be an option?  To some extent, your "roadmap" will just have you building up a lot of stuff nbviewer provides with zero effort.  (But if the objective is to learn that sort of web stuff, fine).
- I'm an enthusiastic user of matplotlib myself and it's great for plots for static presentations and papers... but for online webby stuff I find myself looking enviously at D3.js (or [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) seems to be an attempt to do a python equivalent).
- You say you're starting a PhD.  Beware of disappearing down tech "rabbit holes" which don't advance you towards the goal of submitting your thesis.  Learning numpy/scipy/matplotlib may well be valuable tools for GR research (assuming that's your topic).  But Gunicorn and Django probably not so much (another reason ipython notebooks and nbviewer might be a simpler route).

Comment: Ad i) Will look into the Amazon EC2. Ad ii) The interface should be more sophisticated than a mere CAS notebook, but of course, in the background, there will be such a notebook. Ad iii) Bokeh looks interesting, will take a look at it. Ad iv) I will have a real project, this one will just be for fun. I have some background in webdeveloping, but never anything this scale.